# How does name spacing works using PSR4 in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I am a novice laravel developer and I am trying to understand how namespacing works in here. So I was learning about the Repository pattern and decided to go ahead and implement it in my project.

So I created a directory called `archive` and then loaded it using PSR4 in my composer.json file like so:

```
"Archive\\": "archive/"
```

Now I created a `Repositories` folder in my `archive` folder where I will be creating all the repositories. And I am namespacing files in it like so:

```
namespace Archive\Repositories;
```

Which seems to working fine. Then I created a `Contracts` folder inside the `Repositories` folder which will hold all the interfaces to the implementations I am going to use like `UserRepositoryInterface` for example. And I am namespacing files in the Contracts folder like so:

```
namespace Archive\Repositories\Contracts;
```

Which is working fine too.

Now my doubt lies in the concrete implementations I am trying to make in the `Repositories` folder. Like for example there is a `DbUserRepository` which implements The `UserRepositoryInterface` in the Contracts folder.

Now since I am new to this I tried:

```
class DbUserRepository implements Contacts\UserRepositoryInterface
```

And it works just fine but then I thought I should `use` it on top of the file like so:

```
use Contacts\UserRepositoryInterface;
```

And I could just do:

```
class DbUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
```

And it should work fine according to me but it gives me a class not found exception but when I do something like:

```
use Archive\Repositories\Contacts\UserRepositoryInterface;
```

It works fine now. But this is where I am blurry. Inside the `DbUserRepository` I am in the nampspace of `Archive\Repositories` already so why doesn't it just go on to look into the Contracts folder from there? Why do I need to specify the full this as `use Archive\Repositories\Contacts\UserRepositoryInterface;`

Why can't I just say:

```
use Contacts\UserRepositoryInterface;
```

I hope my question is not too confusing. Although my code is working now but I am blurry how namespacing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are pretty simple:

1. All `namespace` and `use` statements always use *fully qualified names* (FQN), meaning they always start from the global namespace and are not relative to anything else. `use Foo\Bar` always means `\Foo\Bar`, no matter what namespace you're in.
2. All literal mentions of names inside the rest of the code are resolved relative to the current namespace and/or aliases established with `use` statements. `new Foo`, `extends Foo` and such either mean `__NAMESPACE__\Foo`, or whatever `Foo` you might have aliased in some `use` statement.

If you want to shorten names, you need to use `use` statements which use the FQN of the class, not relative to the current namespace.